# How to write command to file in batch?

Tags: batch-file

In batch, is there a way to write the command to run into a file?

For example my script is:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 >> file.txt
```

I want to include `ping 127.0.0.1` into my file.txt so I would know which command produced which output.

Of course I could simply do:

```
echo "ping 127.0.0.1" >> file.txt
ping 127.0.0.1 >> file.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling the batch script, leave `echo on` and output the entire script.

#### Command Line

```
script.bat >> file.txt
```

#### Script.bat

```
@echo on
ping "127.0.0.1"
```

#### This can also be self-invoked by the script with

```
@echo off
if /i not "%~1"=="self" call "%~f0" self >> file.txt & goto :EOF
@echo on
:: Everything (including commands) after this echo will be displayed in the file
ping "127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: Can you please explain the line after @echo off?

Comment: `if /i not "%~1"=="self"` This is checking if the first parameter to the script is the word 'self'.  I am using this as an indication to see if the script was started by itself. `call "%~f0" self` Is starting a new run of the script with the `self` word parameter.  `>> file.txt` Is redirecting the output of the script to the text file. `& goto :EOF` is exiting this instance of the script since we started a new one. This line makes it possible for the script to capture itself rather than the user having to manually specify the `>> file.txt` output capture.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
@echo on
```

before a block of commands, you want to log, and an

```
@echo off
```

after that?

```
@echo off
rem what i want to do
rem some commands (setting variables etc.)
@echo on
ping 127.0.0.1" >> file.txt
ipconfig /all >>file.txt
@echo off
rem some other commands (deleting temporary files etc)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will still only capture the command output.  The commands themselves will only be displayed on the command line.  The whole script must be captured to include the commands in the file.